# How to update standalone ESXi / PowerEdge server?

Tags: vmware-esxi, dell-poweredge

I have a small installation of ESXi 6.5 U2 on a PowerEdge T620 server.  I installed this about a year ago and it's running 6.5 U2.  I'd like to update to U3 (latest build), but I have a few questions I can't seem to find the answer to...

1. For a small installation like this, is it easier to manually apply updates, or better to use VCenter Update Manager?
2. Is it important to continue to use the Dell specific ISOs for the updates, or OK to download ESXi updates?
3. Do I manually update VCSA prior to updating to U3?

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 4):

1. The update manager is good, good way to learn it if you havnt yet. After the config you will know when update will be offered.
2. I always used the ISO for big update like in your case and left the update manager find all missing KB after. The why is some update is more of a reinstall over, then I prefer to have the latest driver built-in inside my ESX. Is it necessary? no, but I think it’s better in the long term.
3. Yes, it’s the first thing you update, always.